# How to get asp:textbox contents for a function that's inside a <script> tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sweetalert

Here is the entire code I have for a simple login page done in ASP.NET:

```
<p></p>
User:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<p></p>
Pass:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<p></p>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" />
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="buttona" type="button">Sweet Alert!</button>
</div>
<script>
    $('#buttona').click(function () {
        if (('#TextBox1').valueOf == "user" && ('#TextBox2').valueOf == "pass") {
            swal("Yay!", "You logged in succesfully", "success");
        }
        else {
            swal("Oh noez", "That's incorrect", "error");
        }
    });
</script>
```

The goal is to show a positive message when the login is successful, and an error message when it's not (using SweetAlert).

My issue is that it's always showing the "Incorrect" message, and I assume what's wrong is that it's not reading the TextBox contents properly (the syntax doesn't look very correct to me but I'm not sure how it's supposed to be). I've tried replacing `.valueOf` with `.text` as well but it didn't help.

How can I get the contents (text) that get inputted in each `asp:TextBox` ?

Comment: `('#TextBox1').val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get TextBox1 and TextBox2 values by

```
var textbox1 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
var textbox2 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').value;
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.